# Column Data Calculations - Default

Tags: 2013, list, column

Working in SP2013...I want to have a default number appear in the column.  However, the number will change every two weeks by 1.  For instance, the default value is 23, but in two weeks it will be 24 (23+1).  Since, I want the number to increase by 1 every two weeks - I am thinking to add a data calculation formula.  Any thoughts for anyone that has attempted this before.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use workflows to this, workflow start on create, pause 1 day and add 1 to the number and pause more 1 day in a continuos cicle.

Comment: Wow... I did not think about using a workflow.  Can I use with one of the Out-of-Box workflows?  Thanks, Diego Hillesheim.

Comment: Use Workflow of the List. this workflow should start on create a new item, and start your count.