# Tracker Calculated Column

Tags: 2013

I have a Activity Date field in my list where user enters date and right after the date input the Countdown (Calculated) column should start the count from 30 and every next day it should decrease the count of Countdown ...once it reaches to 0 (after 30 days) the counter should stop automatically.

=[Activity Date] + 30 is giving me the date which is 30 days ahead. please guide how to achieve the task

Comment: With a Workflow, Calculated Columns do not update like Excel does

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this through calculated column field.  The calculated column data is not stored and values are generated on the fly.  You can create a workflow to update the values. Similar discussion [here also](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84704/column-data-calculations-default?rq=1).